The default Apache web server page says to replace a file before continuing use. Why?
The server currently runs on localhost only. Why should I replace the index.html file? What do I replace it with? I will eventually be using it to create an SSH tunnel.


Shorter version...
The point of installing apache is to have a webserver.
The file /var/www/html/index.html is the default top web page you get when you visit the webserver.  This is where you put the start of the content.
If you are not replacing that file or configuring a different top page, either your webserver is full of hidden content (with a boring default top page) or or perhaps you are not adding any content and there's not a point in running a webserver at all.
If the point of this system is to have an ssh tunnel, and you are not updating the webserver content, then perhaps the webserver is an unneeded service, and you should also look for other unneeded services and remove them all.  Every running service is a potential security risk, and if you are not using it, it is an uneeded extra security risk that could be removed.  Unused services with default configurations are sometimes more of a risk than if they were in use and configured for a specific purpose.

I agree with everything but the "is the first web page you get when you visit the webserver" and "If you are not replacing that file either your webserver is full of hidden content (with a boring default top page) or or perhaps you are not adding any content and there's not a point in running a webserver at all" point; the server may be configured to not use Autoindex, to point to a PHP file or to perform a redirect to an app's root somewhere else, perhaps defined using an alias (as it's the case with PHPMyAdmin). For basic use cases, that's probably true though

Good point...I'm describing and assuming you will not modify the default configuration either.  Fixed.

TL;DR
Don't bother at all replacing it if you don't have a better use for it; the file isn't harmful per se, and the suggestion to replace it is based off the (often fair) assumption that you'll want to use it, and that you'll want to use it to show something other than "It works!" in case the document root is accessed, which overall is often a fair assessment, but this is not always the case; many configurations don't require using an index.html file in the document root at all.
Instead, think about uninstalling Apache if you don't have a use for Apache at all. Setting up SSH tunnels doesn't require Apache at all, so unless Apache has been installed as a dependency for something else, just go ahead and uninstall Apache.

I can't think of any compelling reason to replace that file, other than... having the webserver do something other than saying "It works!" when accessing its document root. Which is often the case, but changing index.html isn't always required. It really depends on your use case.
I agree that the wording comes across as "intimidating", and I can see why one may wonder what would happen if they don't do that. Essentially, there's nothing inherently wrong or harmful in leaving that index.html file as is.
I think that paragraph should be read as in "this is just a placeholder, go ahead and replace it" - with a strong assumption that you'll want to replace index.html with a index.html that does something.
But I could easily make the case that replacing that file could not be mandatory (or useful) at all, depending on what you want to do with the webserver: for example, what if you just wanted Apache to act like a proxy? In that case you'd probably configure Apache to proxy incoming requests for whatever URI, making index.html downright unreachable.
(Admittedly, in this case it'd probably make sense to remove it, but certainly not to replace it, and anyways that would be optional).
Also, e.g., if you wanted to manage MySQL via PHPMyAdmin and you installed PHPMyAdmin, Apache would be installed as a dependency of PHPMyAdmin, but PHPMyAdmin would live in its own alias /phpmyadmin, and you'd access it at http://localhost/phpmyadmin. Again, no compelling reason to "replace" index.html other than maybe showing a more user-friendly page in case you're not the only user accessing the webserver. But even in that case, if the purpose of the webserver was just to let users manage MySQL via PHPMyAdmin, a simple redirect to /phpmyadmin would probably serve better than a custom index.html.
So, what to do with index.html really depends on your use case. But in general, it's not wrong or harmful to not replace it per se.

“I've always read that paragraph as in "this is just a placeholder, go ahead and replace it" - with a strong assumption that you'll want to replace index.html with a index.html that does something.” I figured this to be the case, bit am super new to this. As you said, ( I ‘ll do more research and) I”ll figure out if I need Apache at all or need to replace the default page.

@metanow I added a better example. On a machine of mine, I have PHPMyAdmin installed to visually manage a few MySQL databases. PHPMyAdmin runs as a webapp on top of Apache, and on that machine the only purpose of having Apache running is using PHPMyAdmin. In that case, it wouldn't make sense to replace index.html, it'd probably make sense to redirect requests accessing the webserver's root to PHPMyAdmin, as it's the only virtualhost running on the server. So really it depends on what you want to do with the webserver

I’ll be remote port forwarding.
